# Cassandra Cluster nodetool status refused exception

Tags: cassandra-cluster

I am new to Cassandra and to creating my first cluster which is a two-node cluster, each node is an EC2 instance they are in the same region and have the same availability zone so I chose the EC2Snitch.
I have installed java 8 and Cassandra 4.1.3 after configuring everything rebooting the instances and restarting cassandra I always get **nodetool: Failed to connect to '127.0.0.1:7199' - ConnectException: 'Connection refused (Connection refused)'.**
I tried several solutions and fixed many errors now I get this system log after getting the nodetool status refused:
**tail -f system.log
at io.netty.util.concurrent.PromiseTask.runTask(PromiseTask.java:98)
at io.netty.util.concurrent.ScheduledFutureTask.run(ScheduledFutureTask.java:170)
at io.netty.util.concurrent.AbstractEventExecutor.safeExecute(AbstractEventExecutor.java:164)
at io.netty.util.concurrent.SingleThreadEventExecutor.runAllTasks(SingleThreadEventExecutor.java:472)
at io.netty.channel.epoll.EpollEventLoop.run(EpollEventLoop.java:384)
at io.netty.util.concurrent.SingleThreadEventExecutor$4.run(SingleThreadEventExecutor.java:989)
at io.netty.util.internal.ThreadExecutorMap$2.run(ThreadExecutorMap.java:74)
at io.netty.util.concurrent.FastThreadLocalRunnable.run(FastThreadLocalRunnable.java:30)
at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:750)
INFO  [StorageServiceShutdownHook] 2023-12-25 07:29:36,122 HintsService.java:235 - Paused hints dispatch**